# SPARQL DBpedia query times out

Tags: python, sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to execute a fairly simple SPARQL query on DBPedia from Python, as follows:

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON
city_name = 'Manhattan'
query = """select * 
               where {
               ?URI rdfs:label ?name.
               filter(regex(str(?name), "^%s"))
           }"""%(city_name)
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
sparql.setQuery(query)
result = sparql.query().convert()
```

I want to retrieve all entities that match a given city in the first part of their name. I know that's a lot of entities but it executes fine in the DBPedia test browser [here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).

Whenever I try to run the above query in Python I end up with a timeout error:

```
EndPointInternalError: EndPointInternalError: endpoint returned code 500 and response. 

Response:
Virtuoso S1T00 Error SR171: Transaction timed out
```

Any advice on avoiding this timeout error? I realize that I might have to make my query more specific to tighten the bounds of the search.

Comment: In the Web interface, the query doesn't timeout because there is usually an early termination value of `30000ms` set, thus, it returns all results found in the given time. This value isn't set if you run a query from a remote application. (but could be set by adding `timeout=30000` to the HTTP request) Indeed, such an anytime feature might lead to incomplete result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a full text search first with [`bif:contains`](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlrulefulltext/), and filter that afterwards:

```
SELECT * {
  ?uri rdfs:label ?name .
  ?name bif:contains "Manhattan" . # Or "'Manhattan*'"
  FILTER(STRSTARTS(?name, "Manhattan"))
}
```

Comment: That works! Thank you for explaining. What is the "bif" field?

Comment: It's used to access Virtuoso's full text index; see http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlrulefulltext/